# thタグにマウスオーバーした際、マウスオーバーしているthタグの枠線を青色に変えたい

Tags: html, css

現在は下記のソースのように、thタグの枠線は白に設定しています。
マウスオーバーした際に、この枠線を青に変えたいのですが方法が分かりません。

```css
*現在のCSS(対象のthタグ部分のみ)
table.dataTable thead th {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
table.dataTable thead th:hover {
    border: 太さ デザイン　色 ;
}
```